# Configure Retry for Wallaby or ExUnit

Tags: erlang, elixir, ex-unit, wallaby

Currently I'm developing browser tests but sometimes they are flaky so I want to add retry to those tests, Idk if there is an easy way to add retry to a project with Wallaby and ExUnit by configuration or if there is an library out there. Thanks

Comment: I've used the `httpoison_retry` package (https://hex.pm/packages/httpoison_retry)  for apps doing web-scraping (which is also highly prone to error), but I don't know if that's of any use to you using Wallaby...

Comment: @Everett I'll take a look, thanks